# Python Pyodbc Multiple value insert with variable and list of lists

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, pyodbc

I collect each row from an excel sheet and then I want to insert the data I find into a database while making it as quick as possible (100,000s of inserts). However, my excel sheet does not have the date and I want to get the date from my python code. I want to first insert the date into the query at the first (?) and then the list elements following. However this function only allows for 2 things, the sql and the values. Basically I want a way to insert my run_date variable into insert and then use the list values as the other values. Below is my code:

```
#data is a list of lists
def insert_data_in_db(data, run_date):
    server = 'serv' 
    database = 'db' 
    username = 'user' 
    password = 'pass' 
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
    cursor = cnxn.cursor()

    cursor.fast_executemany = True

    sql = "INSERT INTO table1(date, val1, val2, val3, VALUES ((?),(?),(?),(?))"

    cursor.executemany(sql, run_date, data)
    cursor.close()
    cursor.commit()
```

Comment: Why not add the date into `data`?

Comment: That could be a possibility. I'd like to see if there was a workaround for this though.

Comment: Sure, you could use `list.insert` or comprehension-style syntax like `[[my_date, *item] for item in data]`

Comment: This only adds a new value at the start of the list, not into all of the lists inside the list. Unless I am doing this wrong. If I'd need to do it for every single one, this would also be slower.

Comment: If you will be adding the same date to each row then you can just put a date literal in your SQL command text, e.g., `… VALUES ('2022-01-23', ?, ?, …)`